# Problems inserting an image

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to use a macro to insert a local image into certain cells. 
I have already created the following code, but it returns the error "Unable to get the Insert proberty of Pictures Class".

I'm still a VBA beginner and I'm trying to learn VBA and unfortunately I can't do that much with this bug.

This is my code:

```
    Dim Pic As Picture
    Dim PicPath As String
    Dim ImageCell As Range

    PicPath = "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\streifen.jpg"

    Set ImageCell = Worksheets("Manual").Range("C49:E49")
    Set Pic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PicPath)

    With Pic
        .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Left = ImageCell.Left
        .Top = ImageCell.Top
        .Width = ImageCell.Width
        .Height = ImageCell.Height
    End With
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: I get the error  "Run-time Error 1004: Unable to get the Insert proberty of Pictures Class".

Comment: are you sure the picture exists at that path?

Comment: Yes I am sure. The path is correct. But I moved the picture to C:\ and then it worked. 
Any idea why?

Comment: JeffUK is right, this error occurs if the image is missing. Is `username` in your path a placeholder for the actual username?

Comment: Yes its just a placeholder for here. Maybe I made a error while copy and paste the path. No idea why, now its also working with the other path.

Comment: Great. Just a hint to your code: You specify the size for the image according to some cells in sheet `"Manual"`, but you place the image to `Activesheet`. Are you aware that this can be different sheets?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Yes I'm aware. I create the Sheet in the same macro before the picture part and set size and high of the row and column.

Comment: @wit4r7 that error means the picture is unavailable at that path.. either it can't be found or it can't be loaded due to permissions.